# return string from custom class in a list

Tags: java, class, list

I have a class Player

```
public Player (String name, int num) {
    name = name;
    num= num;
}
```

//getters and Setters

then I will have a list of players

```
List<Player> listPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

I need to make a method to return the player name given the number

```
String getPlayerName(int num){
    ...
}
```

I can make the method seeing all the list but I want to do this in a more efficient way.
Can someone give me some tips?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A method of which class?

Comment: You should try to formulate your question more clearly. For instance, that is not a class that you have posted, but a constructor. Also, your last phrase ("i make the method...") is nearly unreadable... We all get what you want (maybe ^^), but the question is not clean.

Comment: well that type of answers is worst that no answer at all.
I'm not a native speaker of English sorry.
i know that is the constructor is only a example i think the other persons that help understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Map<Integer, Player>` to store all players. Fetching a player from a map by his `num` will be very efficent:

```
map.get(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've *only* got the list, there's nothing you can do that would be more efficient than iterating through the list, finding the player with the right number and returning the name.

I'd be tempted to change the method to just

```
public Player getPlayerByNumber(int num)
```

though, and let the caller get the name afterwards. It's more flexible if you later want to fetch other values.

If you're willing to change your data structures, you could use a `Map<Integer, Player>` instead of a list - something like a `HashMap` would then allow efficient access. If you need to preserve insertion order, you'd want to use a `LinkedHashMap`, but that may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're trying to return a player based on his number, the "right" data structure would be a Map, then you'd use playerMap.get(playerNumber) to get the Player corresponding to that number.

Answer (score 0):

```
String getPlayerName(int num) {

for(Player player:listPlayers) {
    if(player.getNum() == num) {
    return player.getName();
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: int is NOT an Object so you cannot use equals

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public String getPlayerName(int num){

   for (Player p : listPlayers){

           if (p.getNum()==num){

              return p.getName();
              break();
             }


    }

           return null;

}
```

**For better approach use Collection such as Map**

Comment: Why break after the return ? And what happens if you specify a number that's not present ?

Comment: After the loop gets over..the method is exhausted if no match is found with a null value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `ArrayList<Player>` you could have a `Map<Integer, Player>`, then you can access the Player using your `num`:

```
Map<Integer, Player> listPlayerList = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();

// fill in your players with the following line
listPlayerList.add(player.getNum(), player);

// remove a player
listPlayer.remove(player.getNum();

// get player with specific num
Player p = listPlayer.get(num);
String name = p.getName();

// iterate over players
for (Player p: listPlayer.values()) {
  doStuffWith(p);
}
```

If you can not change your `ArrayList` to a `Map`, then your out of luck and have to iterate over your `ArrayList` and check the `num` of every entry.